# Jar file runs on Windows but not Ubuntu (JDK 1.8, compiled with NetBeans)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I made a program with java in NetBeans 8.2 using JDK version 1.8 and the program compiled and ran on my windows machine. I then transferred the project folder containing all files (as well as the jar file in dist) over to my Ubuntu machine.

I entered `java -version` in terminal and got 1.8.0_252 on my linux machine and got 1.8.0_231 on Windows. I don't think this difference means the wrong version is being used.

When I tried to run the program on Linux with the command `java -jar "jarFile".jar` I got the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class kreact.KReact`. I don't understand why this is happening, as the class was found when I ran the same command from Windows cmd to open the jar file.

Thank you for any answers in advance :)

Comment: Please show the contents of your Manifest.MF file(s) here

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: 'Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: kreact.KReact' also did not do anything different. I then put a nonsense class name in here and the error was still 'Error: Could not find or load main class kreact.KReact'

Comment: Could it maybe be something to do with the fact that the file is a JavaFX file?

Comment: Does your main class extend `javafx.application.Application`? Does your Linux machine have JavaFX installed? Note that, if I remember correctly, the Linux distribution of Java 8 did not include JavaFX and you had to install it separately.

Comment: Yes, I think this may be the problem, as I used javac to compile the class and it threw loads of errors, with the first being with javafx.application.Application

Comment: @OwenCook So... Any updates on your problem?

Comment: I went and downloaded java fx and I can't fully remember which version of java I downloaded it from now but it still didn't allow the program to run. I then tried to download netbeans including javafx but this still did not work. What is the best way to get javafx for linux? I haven't managed to find anything anywhere else